# Using intent to call a fragment from another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am using a viewpager control to host three fragments.I have placed a button in each fragment to go to the next fragment.So i wanted to know as how to go from one fragment to another using intent?

The main purpose is to create a sign up form which has been divided into three fragments.The code is shown below:

The main activity:

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyPagerAdapter pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
         pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    }

}
```

The first fragment:

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentBlue extends Fragment {
Button btnnext1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
        btnnext1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnnext1);

        btnnext1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FragmentGreen.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

The second fragment:

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentGreen extends Fragment {
Button btnnext2;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_green, container, false);
        btnnext2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnnext2);
        btnnext2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FragmentPink.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

The third fragment:

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentPink extends Fragment {
Button btnnext3;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pink, container, false);
        btnnext3=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnnext3);
        btnnext3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

The adapter for the viewpager:

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new FragmentBlue());
        fragments.add(new FragmentGreen());
        fragments.add(new FragmentPink());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

The custom class for the viewpager:

```
package pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = false;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

The code which i am using now shows the following error on clicking the first button:

```
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo/pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo.FragmentGreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:824)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo.FragmentBlue$1.onClick(FragmentBlue.java:25)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-20 10:54:18.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9401):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So the question is how to use intent in between fragments.Is there a better way to divide the sign up form into three parts without using viewpager?

Comment: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all the fragments are within the same ViewPager and you just want to be navigated to that fragment then you dont need any `Intents`. all you need to is :

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(POSITION, true);
```

here POSITION is an integer.

Now the view pager is in `Activity` but the `Button` is inside `Fragment` so you need to do this create this method inside your activity

```
public void selectFragment(int position){
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true); 
// true is to animate the transaction
}
```

and call like this inside your `OnClickListener`:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).selectFragment(POSITION_YOU_WANNA_SELECT);
```

Comment: i get the error void is invalid type for the method selectFragment

Answer (score 14):

You can't call your Fragment like this,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FragmentGreen.class);
  view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
  getActivity().finish();
```

you need to call your fragment like this way

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    FragmentGreen llf = new FragmentGreen();
    ft.replace(R.id.listFragment, llf);
    ft.commit();
```

`Intent` is basically used for call one activity from another. For add new `Fragment` you can't use `Intent`. For that you have to use `FragmentManager` and for open fragment `FragmentTransaction`.

for more details go [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: What should i use at R.id.listFragment?

Comment: listFragment is a id for Fragment container. So you have to add one FrameLayout in one xml file with id of listFragment for add fragment in that layout.

Comment: First check this one  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FragmentGreen.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish(); and then tell me

Answer (score 1):

```
public  class Fragment3 extends Fragment{

    Button button;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view;
        Fragment fragment;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_4, container, false);
        button=view.findViewById(R.id.exit);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                assert fm != null;
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                FragmentLogin llf = new FragmentLogin();
                ft.replace(R.id.FrameButton, llf);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.fragment_blue, (Fragment)new FragmentGreen()).commit();
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Home");
```