# How to implement Intent to call fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using tabbed activity. I have used a button in the first tab for which on button click it should to the second tab.

How can I use Intent to call Second Fragment from First Fragment?

Here is the code of my both fragments.

First Fragment:

```
package com.touchsmart.spectacular.ui.Fragments;

import....

public class ShippingFragment extends Fragment {

  private LinearLayout addnew;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shipping, container, false);

    addnew = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.addnew);

    addnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),PaymentFragment.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Check Out");
}
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
package com.touchsmart.spectacular.ui.Fragments;

import...

public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);

    return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Check Out");
    }
    }
```

The code which I am using now shows the following error on clicking the first button:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.touchsmart.spectacular, PID: 18942
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.touchsmart.spectacular/com.touchsmart.spectacular.ui.Fragments.PaymentFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:146)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:932)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1047)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:944)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:933)
    at com.touchsmart.spectacular.ui.Fragments.ShippingFragment$1.onClick(ShippingFragment.java:36)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

anyone provide me a solution to get through this.Thanks..

Comment: `PaymentFragment` is a `Fragment` you should replace it with `ShippingFragment` using `FragmentManager`

Comment: go to this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945639/7226732]

Answer (score 0):

You can not call Intent to calling fragment.
You have to use this code if you want to add fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit();
```

Or if you want to replace fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentFragment.class);
startActivity(i);
```

It can't work and start `Fragment` by using `startActivity()`. you have to use it when you want to change only `Activity`.

---

When you want to replace `Fragment`, use `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction`.

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Please read this [Replace One Fragment with Another](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html?hl=en), It will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make your UI more Interactive and good looking, I'm gonna share what I've implemented.

Just to access your `viewPager` from the fragment's java file, declare your `viewPager` as below in your tabbed activity.

```
public static ViewPager viewPager;
```

Then in the `onClick` method or `onClickListener` of a button, you can just use this.

```
TabbedActivity.viewPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

This will smooth scroll your `viewpager` to the Payment activity, and yes, if you want to limit the user from scrolling directly you can disable the scrolling of viewPager, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814054/8244632).

But this only works if you've implemented the fragments as below in the `FragmentAdapter` in tabbed activity.

```
@Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new ShippingFragment ();
                case 1:
                    return new PaymentFragment ();

            }
            return null;
        }
```

You can also shift the focus to left if user wants to go back to `ShippingFragment` by just

```
TabbedActivity.viewPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT);
```

And yes, it's working as I first test before posting answers, silly me.